# I cannot get the value of reduce in result, only get the key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

In map function, I want to get the result that like ***hello  world  1***

```
context.write(new Text(firstStr + "\t" + secondStr), new LongWritable(1));
```

And in my reduce function,

```
private LongWritable result = new LongWritable();
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<LongWritable> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      long sum = 0;
      for (LongWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      //context.write(new Text(key.toString().getBytes("GB18030")), result);
      context.write(key, result);
}
```

in my result, I find I get the data in my part-r-00000 like that:

```
hello  world
hello  tom
thank  you
```

in fact, what I want to get the result is as follows

```
hello  world  1
hello  tom   1
```

I don't know what happened, Please help me? thanks

Comment: Can you post the whole code please (including the main/Driver class)? are you sure you are calling the reducer posted here and not an older version?

Comment: you are right.  And i get the right result after modified. thanks